# Need to Redirect Category Page On Home Page of Lightspeed Based Webstore

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have some trouble with redirection of my category page to Home page.

Have category page www.example.com/sale-baby that want to redirect on home www.example.com from .Htacess.

Using Lightspeed Webstore for the website.

I try to use simple rule but its not working.

If possible can give right suggestion for that.

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]` 
“L” indicates that it’s the last instruction and “R” means redirect, and “301” means a permanent redirect.

other way:

Position the cursor after the HEAD tag in the code.
`http://www.newsite.com/newurl.html">`

Hope it Help You..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but Using Lightspeed Webstore for the website and its not working.

Comment: so its means in admin configuration of your webstore, overrite to our htaccess.
check it on admin panel of webstore

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220181/htaccess-apache-to-litespeed

check with this may it help you.